# Using Bootstrap Panel - How do I put form next to title?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried at least three proposed solutions from searching on this site, but nothing worked. I got close, but was getting cheated on the panel defeault backround color. For some reason, the background wasn't showing its full height behind my elements. I want to put a form next to the heading. Here is what I have tried.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

      <div class="no-wrap">
        <h3 class="panel-title">My Title</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="no-wrap">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">  
              <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>    
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>   
      </div> 

</div> <!-- end panel-heading -->

<div class="panel-body">
    Body Text    
</div>

</div> <!-- end panel -->
```

All the class you see are bootstrap EXCEPT no-wrap. My css for no-wrap is

```
.no-wrap {
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

So this was my most hopeful solution but it still doesn't work. The form sits below the h3.

I also tried using bootstrap columns inside the panel heading, but that's when the default gray background got obscured.

How can I get this form next to the h3 - all inside the panel heading?? Please note, you can assume that there is plenty of screen width. 99.9% of users will be using a laptop to access this page. The panel is being used to display business reports. Mobile responsiveness is not a priority.

Below is screenshot of what I do NOT want. I want the input form next to the heading.

[image: Below is screenshot of what I do NOT want. I want the input form next to the heading.]

Comment: Could you make a Codepen example with linked assets (BS etc)?
Images also really help to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I do not want. I want the form next to the heading - like on the same line, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;`

[Demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u2w9cf7/)

Comment: Good stuff! Great demo. It's just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. You just need to include GRID OF BOOTSTRAP in your code such as `col-xs-* , col-sm-* , col-md-* , col-lg-*`. Don't need custom css in your case. You could ask me for further question as well.

```html
<HTML>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <h3 class="panel-title">My Title</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>    
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end panel-heading -->

    <div class="panel-body">
      Body Text
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end panel -->
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I had already tried this approach, and for some reason the default background color in the heading gets clipped. In other words, the form displays next to the heading, but the background color shows in only the top vertical half of the div.